# How can I use extract a string within a string of text where the ending anchor has parentheses using a sregular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a problem and this is my first time asking within this community, so please be gentle.
I am trying to extract a string within another string but the problem is that the end string has parentheses and that is messing with the regular expression. I am trying to capture the company name, "SMITH PSYCHIATRIC, INC." using "of" and ("Customer") as the beginning and end anchors.

My sample is:

I, Fred Smith, HEREBY CERTIFY that I am MD of **SMITH PSYCHIATRIC, INC.** ("Customer"), an entity organized under the laws of the State of CA.

I was trying to use (?<=of).*(?=("Customer")) but the parentheses of ("Customer") is messing with the regular expression.

I did try to excape the parentheses like (?<=of).*(?=\("Customer"\)) but it still comes back invalid.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about escaping the parenthesis. You can use a capture group without lookarounds, and get the group 1 value:

```
\bof\s+(.*?)\s*\("Customer"\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KyZfbN/1)

```js
const s = 'I, Fred Smith, HEREBY CERTIFY that I am MD of SMITH PSYCHIATRIC, INC. ("Customer"), an entity organized under the laws of the State of CA.';
const regex = /\bof\s+(.*?)\s*\("Customer"\)/;
const m = s.match(regex);

if (m) console.log(m[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

***Welcome to SO, Andrew***.
You can follow the below code pattern to get what you need.

*String Object :*

> I, Fred Smith, HEREBY CERTIFY that I am MD of SMITH PSYCHIATRIC, INC. ("Customer"), an entity organized under the laws of the State of CA.

*You need  :*

> "SMITH PSYCHIATRIC, INC."

You can follow this code :

```js
"use strict";
const stringObj =
  'I, Fred Smith, HEREBY CERTIFY that I am MD of SMITH PSYCHIATRIC, INC. ("Customer"), an entity organized under the laws of the State of CA.';

// let pattern = /(?<=of).*(?=("Customer"))/;
let pattern = /(?<=of ).*(?=\s[(])/;
 
//output : SMITH PSYCHIATRIC, INC.
console.log(pattern.exec(stringObj)[0]);
```

*Pattern description :* get the matching characters between "of" and " (". Note the space before "(". In case, there is no space in the string object, you can remove the "\s" in the pattern.